# Itemize in awesome-CV

Tags: awesome-cv

I am working on awesome cv (downloaded from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)). I am trying to put the following items in a  bulleted list and in a two-column table. I am not sure how to do it. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item {item 1}
\item {item2}
\item {item 3}
\item {item4}
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make a minimal, but compilable code example (MWE) illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a new environment based on `cvitems`, which I call `cvitems*`, that takes as optional argument the number of columns (default 2).

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{2mm}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\item item 4 with words describing it
\item item 5 with words describing it
\item item 6 with words describing it
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[4]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\item item 6
\item item 7
\item item 8
\item item 9
\item item 10
\item item 11
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The middle `cvitems` environments are to show the spacing.

Comment: I felt the obligation to help him/her but was too slow :P (But didn't look in the documentation to see if was possible). (+1)

Comment: Follow up about egreg's solution. If we wanted to remove the 4 title's ("xxx", "Manager xx", "Swi", "2019"), how would we implement the code. I've tried a bunch of times but cannot get the code to work. Basically I just want to have the header EXPERIENCE and then bullet points directly below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@mildbubble, you can use this code in order to have bullet points directly below "Experience" :

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-2\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{} % Job title
{} % Organization
{} % Location
{} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[3]
\item \textbf{item 1}
\item \textbf{item 2}
\item \textbf{item 3}
\item \textbf{item 4}
\item \textbf{item 5}
\item \textbf{item 6}
\item \textbf{item 7}
\item \textbf{item 8}
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}
```

And here is the output : [image]

Hope it helps.