# bulleted items in a table in awesome cv

Tags: fontawesome, awesome-cv

I am working on awesome cv (downloaded from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)). I got an answer form @egreg on how to put items in columns. But I want to change the appearance of the bullet items. Here is hes answer with default templates commands and style of itemize:

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{2mm}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\item item 4 with words describing it
\item item 5 with words describing it
\item item 6 with words describing it
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems}
\item item 1 with words describing it
\item item 2 with words describing it
\item item 3 with words describing it
\end{cvitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[4]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\item item 4
\item item 5
\item item 6
\item item 7
\item item 8
\item item 9
\item item 10
\item item 11
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

How can I change the style of the items to a "ball" or something?

Comment: You could edit your post here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/450013/120578 and add a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578)... The code you gave is just a part of it. If you give a full example you will sure get help. If not, may be you will get, but may be not.

Comment: I edited the post there and I am going to delete this one. The actual code is gigantic. I am struggling with making a MWE out of it. I thought if someone has already used awesome-cv, they might be able to help. Any thoughts?

Comment: You dont need all the templete's code... Just help people with the basics of the code.. Just add their resume.tex and remove unneded parts + add your specific problem's code

Comment: I used the freedom to change your question to be about the style of the items since this was in your previous question before edit and maybe is a way to keep this question useful (for you and others) without need to delete.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Thanks for showing me how to create an MWE for these kind of problems.

Comment: You are welcome @math. In this forum is good to upvote the answers you like. This way you show people that the answer is good (or useful, or better than others) and you show your appreciation too. I don't know if you have the priviledge to upvote, but when you get it, try to upvote at least the usefull unvoted and only answers... just because in other case they can be deleted with the post. This way you prevent from deletion of the post. and I don't mean this answer but other answers at other's post. This can be deleted just from you and if accepted may be not even from you. Just informing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way (The code is commented about usage):

I used the styling of bullet from @Fran's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72814/120578).

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

%koleygr: Here is the code needed for out item-table

%From: Fran's answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72814/120578
% tkiz ball item
\newcommand*\circled[2][\scriptsize]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[circle,ball color=awesome-red, shade, 
 color=black,inner sep=1.2pt] (char) {#1 #2};}}



\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Creates a tabular that accepts \item command:
% #1 is the size like "\scriptsize or \normalsize [default] or \tiny etc
% #2 size of tabular like "c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cc" or "p{3cm}@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{3cm}"
% #3 integer larger than 0 gives numbered items else unnumbered
% #4 distance from the ball (of the item)
\newcounter{myitemscounter}

\NewEnviron{myitems}[4][\scriptsize]
{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\let\olditem\item%
\ifnum#3>0
\setcounter{myitemscounter}{0}%
\def\item{%
\stepcounter{myitemscounter}%
\circled[#1]{\themyitemscounter}\hspace{#4}%
}
\else
\def\item{%
\circled[#1]{\phantom{1}}\hspace{#4}%
}
\fi
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{#2}%
\BODY
\end{tabular*}%
\let\item\olditem
}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Experience}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
%\begin{cvitems}
%\item {item 1}
%\item {item2}
%\item {item 3}
%\item {item4}
%\end{cvitems}
\begin{myitems}[]{p{6.5cm} @{\extracolsep{2cm}} p{6.5cm}}{1}{4pt}
\item 2004--2014 Manager of a No-name company and lost my time with them&\item 2014 --2016 Manager of a Huge company that solved the equation $y=3\cdot x$ where $x=1$ \\[4pt]
\item 2016--2018 Unemployed because of the world's biggest Economical Crisis.&\item 2018 --(till die) Hope to not lose my time with your Company
\end{myitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{Manager xx } % Job title
{xxx} % Organization
{Swi} % Location
{2019} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
%\begin{cvitems}
%\item {item 1}
%\item {item2}
%\item {item 3}
%\item {item4}
%\end{cvitems}
\begin{myitems}[]{p{6.5cm} @{\extracolsep{2cm}} p{6.5cm}}{0}{4pt}
\item 2004--2014 Manager of a No-name company and lost my time with them&\item 2014 --2016 Manager of a Huge company that solved the equation $y=3\cdot x$ where $x=1$ \\[4pt]
\item 2016--2018 Unemployed because of the world's biggest Economical Crisis.&\item 2018 --(till die) Hope to not lose my time with your Company
\end{myitems}
}
\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]